# Differential Op-Amp Input Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

I want to use a rail-to-rail op-amp as a differential amplifier.

The op-amp is supplied by 3.3V and the input signals swings from 0 to 5V. I want the output to swing between 0 and 2.5V.

My question is if the schematic below safe, in the sense that the inputs of the op-amps will not see voltages higher than VCC+0.3V.

I assume it is as the positive side of the input signal goes through that voltage dividers but I am not sure.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7JR4U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why are you using a differential amplifier? What op-amp is it?

Comment: I want to remove common mode noise and I cannot be sure that the negative side of the signal is truly at ground level. AD8628

Comment: @Andyaka Oh yes, R4 should have been 5k as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input over-voltage section (page 17) in the data sheet says this: -

> *If inputs are subject to overvoltage, appropriate series resistors
>   should be inserted to limit the diode current to less than 5 mA
>   maximum.*

Given that you are worried about protecting against over-voltage, the input resistors (R1 and R2) may be subject to a voltage difference of 5 volts - 3.3 volts = 1.7 volts. So, providing that R1 and R2 have a resistance of not less than 340 ohms you will be fine even if R3 and R4 went open circuit.

> *My question is if the schematic below safe, in the sense that the
>   inputs of the op-amps will not see voltages higher than VCC-0.3V.*

I believe you meant VCC + 0.3 volts.